# Scrolling Ionic 1 child view without scrolling parent view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set up scrolling sub-tabs in a tabbed Ionic 1 app. The idea is to have a header with basic informational stuff and a `button-bar` to navigate between the various sub-tabs. The content of these sub-tabs should be able to scroll *without* scrolling the main parent content.

I've been able to set this all up, **except** for getting the child tab content to scroll separately.

Things I've tried:

- Putting the child content in its own `ion-content`. The resulting content completely covers the parent tab content.
- Putting the child content in its own `ion-scroll`. There's a giant ugly scroll bar on the right hand side, and the content doesn't actually scroll.

[I've created a Plunker here that demonstrates what I'm trying to do.](https://plnkr.co/edit/lzFa4RMQTNdCMt7hhl1z?p=preview) Any insights on how to structure something like this gracefully?

[image]

**Parent tab view**

```
<ion-view title="Home">
  <ion-content style="" class="has-header" scroll="false" padding="true">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png">
        <h3>
          <i class="ion-person"></i> Username
          <p>Basic user fact 1</p>
          <p>Basic user fact 2</p>
        </h3>
      </div>

      <div class="button-bar">
         <a class="button button-positive" ui-sref="tab.dash.about">About me</a>
         <a class="button button-assertive" ui-sref="tab.dash.photos">Photos</a>
      </div> 
      <ui-view name="tab-dash-content"></ui-view>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Example tab child content**

```
<ion-scroll direction="y">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
      These 20 items below should scroll without scrolling the section or buttons above!
    </div>
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] track by $index">
      About item: {{i}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: so in other words, you want to make the header section sticky?

Comment: The header section should stay where it is. The content in the `<ui-view>` or `<ion-nav-view>` below should scroll.

Comment: so then yes, you want it "sticky".  there are A LOT of questions here about how to make sticky elements in HTML already;  You might start by searching those out.

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but I'm specifically looking for an Ionic way to do this. The `<ion-view>`, `<ion-content>` and `<ion-scroll>` directives do a lot of special stuff and the answer isn't a pure HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: your plunker is *close*, but from the docs on [ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/):  "Note that it’s important to set the height of the scroll box as well as the height of the inner content to enable scrolling."

Comment: Given the kind of information that I need to display, I don't think I should even be using ion-scroll; I can't determine heights ahead of time. It seems ion-scroll is really meant for dealing with images or other things of known size.